# Why does paramiko return blank line while execute invalid command?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I try to use paramiko to execute an invalid command on remote server

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.10.11.15", 22, "admin", "net")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls1")
print stdout.read()
ssh.close()
```

However, it always returns blank line.
How could I get the error message for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a error message is printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Try printing that instead.